# Is there a way to use array of data as a function variable?

Tags: expression-manipulation, list-manipulation

I have a data that looks something like.

```
{{1,1},{12,1},{7,9},{10,14}, ...... }
```

I want to see if there is an easy way to apply this array of data into a function like the following:

```
f:= Beta[1+a,1+b]Beta[12+a,1+b]Beta[7+a,9+b]........
```

so that I will not have to type them all in

Please help.

Comment: You could also consider `Product[Apply[Beta, {a, b} + args], {args, list}]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
Times @@ Map[ Beta[First[#] + a, Last[#] + b] &, {{1, 1}, {12, 1}, {7, 9}, {10, 14}}]
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! thx!

Answer (score 5):

```
f[a_, b_] := 
 Fold[#1*Beta[#2[[1]] + a, #2[[2]] + b] &, 
  1, {{1, 1}, {12, 1}, {7, 9}, {10, 14}}]

f[a, b]
```

> `Beta[1 + a, 1 + b] Beta[7 + a, 9 + b] Beta[10 + a, 14 + b] Beta[12 + a, 1 + b]`

Answer (score 2):

Or this

```
d = {{1, 1}, {12, 1}, {7, 9}, {10, 14}};
Times@@Beta @@@ (# + {a, b} & /@ d)
```

> > Beta[1 + a, 1 + b] Beta[7 + a, 9 + b] Beta[10 + a, 14 + b] Beta[
> >       12 + a, 1 + b]

Or if you want a,b,d and Beta all to be parameters to a function `f`:

```
f[a_, b_, fn_, d_] := Times@@fn @@@ (# + {a, b} & /@ d)
f[h, i, Beta, {{1, 7}, {2, 8}, {4, 5}}]
```

> > Beta[1 + h, 7 + i] Beta[2 + h, 8 + i] Beta[4 + h, 5 + i]

Comment: Forgot to multiply 'em all. ;)

Comment: Damn, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

More ideas for you:

```
in = {{1, 1}, {12, 1}, {7, 9}, {10, 14}};

Times @@ Inner[Plus, in, {a, b}, Beta]

Times @@ (Beta[# + a, #2 + b] & @@@ in)

Times @@ MapThread[Beta, in\[Transpose] + {a, b}]
```